# Is March 27th, 2012 of significance to SQL Server in a Varchar to Datetime conversion?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlexception, outofrangeexception

I have a stored procedure that takes a datetime parameter which is passed in as a string. Such as this:

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyFancySP]
   @MyStartDate datetime = NULL,
   @MyEndDate datetime = NULL
AS
....
```

Call:

```
EXEC [dbo].[MyFancySP]
   @MyStartDate = N'01/01/2012',
   @MyEndDate = N'03/01/2012'
```

The stored procedure has been working like this forever. Now, here's the interesting part. As soon as I change the date to 03/27/2012 or past it, I get the following error: **The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.**

The only place in the stored procedure where the dates are used is in the where clause. In case it has to do with it, I'll copy it in here as well:

```
WHERE
((@MyStartDate IS NOT NULL AND @MyEndDate IS NOT NULL 
AND d.SomeDate >= @MyStartDate AND d.SomeDate <= @MyEndDate) 
OR @MyStartDate IS NULL AND @MyEndDate IS NULL)
```

Any ideas why I'm getting the out of range exception on March 27th or beyond? This is running on SQL Server 2008 R2 by the way.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the Mayans were a little late with their prediction

Comment: What collation is your server using? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @ChrisShain Server collation and database collation are SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type is `d.SomeDate`? Is it a `NVARCHAR` by any chance? That would explain it, as the WHERE clause would contain in such case an implicit conversion that the rules of [Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) state that should occur as a `DATETIME`. The apparent randomness of the error occurs due to the simple fact that the query scans rows that have invalid dates in the `d.SomeDate` field. In such a case you're dealing with data purity issues and you should fix your tables, preferably by making the column a DATETIME.

In addition:

- always use the canonical date format `YYYYMMMDD` (no delimiters) in string representation: `EXEC [dbo].[MyFancySP]
  N'20120101', N'20120301';`. This format is independent of the host locale, DATEFORMAT and LANGUAGE settings, .
- Read [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html). `WHERE column=@value or @value is null` stops query performance optimizations dead on its track. Read the article.

Comment: d.SomeDate is of type datetime.

Answer (score 2):

Execute the following on each new database connection.

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
```

After you do this, your problem should disappear.  I suspect that your issue is conditioned by a combination of server locale, and whether the day-of-month is 13th to 31st or not.

Not only that you see the error, you may also be fetching data for incorrect periods without noticing; other layers of your software may be correcting for that, but maybe only in some cases.

Comment: I tried this. I'm still getting the same error, just worded differently. It says now "Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime."

Comment: That was my thought too- the server is expecting DD/MM/YYYY (European style) not MM/DD/YYYY (US Style)

Comment: I don't think that makes sense, otherwise 03/26/2012 would error out too (after all there is no 26th month) but that date works fine. The problem only appears on 03/27/2012 and beyond (including 04/01/2012 etc.).

Comment: @Alex - However, the error message wording in the question fits the incorrect DATEFORMAT and the new one doesn't, so I suspect there is also something else.  I'm trying to reproduce the new one that you see now.  Are all your observations from the same server?

Comment: @Alex - Your new message seems to come from .NET.  It seems that your higher level code expects MDY, and you pass in DMY (as I can see in the question).  One or the other has to change, and the connections should be maintained on a fixed culture independent setting.  If you do need to mix the formats, let me know and I'll extend the answer to cover that.

Comment: @JirkaHanika, yes this is all from the same server. The error message is thrown in SQL Server management studio, so the higher level .NET code should not have any bearing.

Comment: @Alex - I was wrong wrt .NET, you are right.  Is the type of `d.SomeDate` a string, or a datetime?  Post your table's schema and your whole procedure.  If you have datetimes stored as strings, post those, too.